# Scheduling tasks in near future

Tags: algorithm, job-scheduling

The question is about scheduling the tasks. Assume that, at any point of time a new task comes in and it needs to be addressed in future. Also, we don't have the information regarding the exact time at which the other tasks are scheduled, but we do know the number of tasks which are scheduled for next *x* hours.

The trivial solution is to, schedule it for the current time. In that case, it might happen that, already there are too many pending tasks, causing ***lag in the execution*** of the task. So, we need to put it in future, such that the lag in execution of the task is not a problem. Also, at the same time I do have a time cap, which specifies that the new task must be performed in that specified deadline.

So, in short the question is that, how we should schedule, the incoming new task so that -

i) The task doesn't get in too much of lag.

ii) The task is performed in the specified deadline.

Assume that all the tasks have equal priority and equal deadline value to meet. Hence first come first serve technique is followed.

Answer (score 1):

Solutions:

1. Specify a priority for each task. Whenever a task with much higher priority will enter the job queue, the currently executing low-priority task will be preempted and the higher priority task will execute within its own time interval. But also another logic during this implementation, so that the lower-priority task won't get starved for a long period of time.
2. Swap the task with another in the job queue using a buffer/backing store depending on the specified time cap for each task. If the currently running task has less time remaining, it should be run until it finishes. Otherwise, it can be swapped with the incoming task which has minimal time cap.

Comment: Assume that all task have equal priority and equal deadline to meet. Hence, first come first serve method is required. But the problem is for the new task, we need to schedule at such point so that it never happens that there are already too much tasks running hence causing lag, but at the same time meet the deadline and gets picked in time.

Comment: The new task can be assigned higher priority than the remaining tasks. The scheduler will automatically pick it up and put in the front of the job queue.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as you really don't want to use a schedule mechanism, but rather a job queue. When a job is finished you start the next job in the queue. If the queue is empty you idle until there is a job to run. If you have multiple CPU cores or there is another benefit from running jobs in parallel you can use a counter to know how many jobs you have currently running.

Comment: Suppose that the queue never gets empty, causing the new task never to be picked up. And this will result in spilling over the deadline for the tasks.